# Storing numbers in an efficient way in computer.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, measure-theory, factorial, fibonacci-numbers

I know that we can write a very large number such as 5040 in only 7!, and imagine I want to store this number in a binary file with the least number of bits.

Saving 5040 takes 13 bits of space, while saving it as 7 (knowing that 7 means 7!) takes only 3 bits. That occupies 4 times less space in a file.

Now I want to show numbers fro 0 to 4096, and if it's not possible, numbers 0 to 255 in any way that it takes less space to store it in binary systems.

I'm looking for ANY KIND OF WAYS (Fibonacci, Factorial, Algebra, Geometric positions, etc.) to do it in an efficient way. I welcome any idea about it. Thank you.

Comment: This is a computer science question, not a mathematics question.

Comment: With 0 to 4095, you have 4096 distinct values to represent, so you need 12 bits. There's no way to do less and still have every possible value.

Comment: It's an interesting idea but I think Information Theory would have a thing or two to say if this was viable at all. Encoding n objects in a code will always require $\log_2 n$ bits.

Comment: You should think about saving such data in numeral systems other than decimal, e.g.  hexadecimal, or even bigger (think about creating your own, which will take less characters = less bits).

Comment: Thank you all for answering. I'm looking not just for one solid way, but a combination of one or two ways to do it. I also thought about making my own way of storing data to take less space, I couldn't come up with a good idea that really works.

Comment: @CuteBoy As others pointed out already: no matter how intricate you make this, you'll always have to use at least $n$ bits to differentiate between numbers $1$ through $2^n$.

Comment: @Bram28 that's right. Normally I need n bits to differentiate between 1 through 2. But, I am looking for any ways including categorization of numbers in two or more categories. If I can show the computer with only 1 bit that a number belongs to a certain category, I can root it back to its original equivalent numbers. For example, if I could show certain numbers with Fibonacci, certain numbers with Factorial, others with a different parameter, in a way that all numbers between 0 and 255 would fit in, it could've been perfect for me. I still can manage a few bits for flagging the categories.

Comment: You still don't seem to understand.  It doesn't matter what kind of categorizations you use.  There are only $2^n$ different strings of $n$ bits.  You can't distinguish more than $2^n$ different objects with those bits.  Of course, if you have "extra bits" to distinguish categories, those extra bits are counted in the $n$.

Comment: I see. I'm still trying to understand it, not done yet. I have an RGB pixel that can be any color within more than 16 million color range. Each R, G, and B can be a number between 0 and 255. I need to assign a unique value for every pixel among these more than 16 million pixels. I was thinking to show their RGB numbers as X, Y, Z coordinates, but with a formula that each R, G, and B would be stored in a number less than 8 bits. Of course numbers less than 128 can be stored in 7 bits, and even less. My big problem is with numbers between 128 to 255. I want to save them in less than 8 bits.

Comment: See also [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity)

Comment: Thank you @lhf I never thought about it. I still wonder how I can save some numbers (for example 0 to 16 million, 0 to 4096, or 0 to 255) in such a way that doesn't take a lot of space. Kolmogorov complexity is a brilliant idea. Must learn how.

Comment: in C#, the smallest integer is called  short int and it stores numbers in the range -32,768 to 32,767 Signed as a 16-bit integer. Even if you put a zero, an short integer will use 16-bits. The Packed-Decimal format is an efficient way to store data. See: https://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2FGUID-0E0191D8-C39A-44D1-BA4C-D67107BAF784%2FHRLHLHCLANU942.html

Answer (score 0):

Via pigeonhole principle, you can't, if you want lossless compression. any compression algorithm that force some lower in bitstring length, will force others higher if it avoids overlap and is therefore lossless.